Move cursor to marker position in leafletjs
I have an image which I rotate by dragging a marker. To continue dragging from same position where user has left dragging previously, I am setting the coordinates of marker to lastRotationPoint.
Here is my code:
            rotateMarker.on('mousedown', (e) => {
              if(lastRotationPoint){
                rotateMarker.setLatLng(lastRotationPoint)
              }
            });
            rotateMarker.on('drag', (e) => {
              const newPos = rotateMarker.getLatLng();
              prevPoint = imageLayer.getCenter();
              if (lastRotationPoint) prevPoint = lastRotationPoint;
              const newAngle = calculateAngleDelta(map, imageLayer.getCenter(), prevPoint, newPos);
              const angDeg = radians2degrees(newAngle);
              imageLayer.setAngle(angDeg, 'deg');
            });
            rotateMarker.on('dragend', (e) => {
              saveImage();
              lastRotationPoint = e.target.getLatLng();
              img_center = imageLayer.getCenter();
              destinationMarkerLoc = getDestinationMarkerLocation(img_center);
              rotateMarker.setLatLng(
                new L.LatLng(
                  destinationMarkerLoc.geometry.coordinates[1],
                  destinationMarkerLoc.geometry.coordinates[0],
                ),
                { draggable: 'true' },
              );
            });

Now rotation is working properly, but the problem is when I perform the mouse down event, marker is shifted to the previous position, but Cursor remains at the original marker postion.
I want the cursor to be on same position as the marker is.
